# how to identify or differentiate the click event on a legend/label (vs) the rest of the chart in ngx-chart?

Tags: angular, label, chart.js, legend, ngx-charts

I've click event on ngx-chart pie chart where clicking anywhere on the pie chart will scroll the page to the bottom of the page except the click on legend or label. ( I need a different behavior for label click).

My click event fires all the time whether the click is on label or chart. Event the event.target shows the same canvas element.

```
public pieChartClicked(e:any):void {
    alert('Chart Clicked');
    console.log('e', e);
    this.isChartClicked = true;
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }
```

How to check if the element is legend/label or the actual chart area.

Comment: I got the answer now.

Comment: There is an attribute called 'active' in Event object which will be an empty array when clicked on label/legend.

Comment: For other elements it will show 'ChartElement'. Here is the logic                     
    public pieChartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log('e', e.active);
    if(e.active.length){
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
      this.isChartClicked = true;
    }
  }